# Extraer imagenes contenidas en celdas de Excel

Tags: php, excel

Vendi un sistema a un cliente y me paso la tabla de productos de su provedor.
Para cada producto tiene una celda con la imagen del mismo..

Algunas hojas del archivo lucen asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De que manera podria recorrer esa Hoja y extraer las imagenes. He probado con SpreadSheetReader ya que trabajo con PHP, y me extrae el codigo y el precio pero que hago con las imagenes?

Comment: con php no sé, pero con VBA se podría hacer un bucle por todas las imágenes y mirar la propiedad `TopLeftCell`, para saber de qué celda viene la imagen.  https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.shape.topleftcell Lo que no sé es si con php puedes leer esa propiedad de alguna manera....

Comment: Eso estaria bueno para ya asociar la imagen a su articulo. Igual no trabajo con VBA. Gracias por tu tiempo